# Replace a div on a ajax call using javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need some help in order to replace some html inside a div with some other html which I get from the server when making the Ajax call.

To make this clear for you guys, I have the following code:

**Code:**

```
<div class="travel-container" id="travel-container">
    <div class="travel-content">

        @using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "sbw_travel_form" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="routes small-12 large-6 column">
                    @Html.Label("Departure Route:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartureRoute, routesSelectList, new { @class = "dropdown", @id = "Outbound-route" })

                    @Html.Label("Return Route:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReturnRoute, routesConverslySelectList, new { @class = "dropdown", @id = "Return-route" })
                </div>

                <div class="dates small-12 large-3 column">
                    @Html.Label("Departure Date:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { Value = Model.DepartureDate.ToShortDateString(), @class = "textbox datepicker ll-skin-melon", @id = "departureDate" })

                    @Html.Label("Return Date:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnDate, new { Value = Model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString(), @class = "textbox datepicker ll-skin-melon", @id = "returnDate" })
                </div>

                <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns"></div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you see that I have put everything inside a class container called travel-container.

What I'm trying to do is to replace the div with the "routes" class with some same div tag when I get new html from the server. The problem is that I need to keep the rest of the html inside the container.

**The ajax call code:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("FindReturnRoutes", "Travel")",
            dataType: "html",
            data: postData,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".travel-content").append(res.loader);
                setTimeout(delay);
            },

            success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".travel-content").find(res.loader).remove();
                    $('.travel-container').html($(data).find(".travel-content"));
                    datepickerLoad();
                    Initializer();
                }, delay);
            }
        });
```

Right now I'm using the find method to find the travel-content div and replace all the content within that div. Have tried putting .routes after and alone but none seem to work. Is find the right solution to use here?

***All I want is to replace the routes div with the new one I get from the ajax call, but still keep the rest of the html without replaceing it all.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code snippet may be helpful for you.

```
$('.travel-container .routes').prepend($(data).find('.routes').html());
```

Comment: Well.. the remove part is right, but the prepend method does not seem to do what it should do.

Comment: I guess the "data" is containing a new .travel-container.. how can retrive the .routes class out of the data?

Comment: The other solution you did worked, just have to do it like this line:
$('.travel-content .replace').prepend(($(data).find(".routes")));

Thx man for helping me. please edit it back to prepend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please:

```
$('.travel-container .travelcontent').html(data);
```

Comment: That does not work at all. This will just replace it all